# Designing a Design matrix

Tags: data-science, linear-regression

I have recently started learning Data Science and I am unable to get grasp of design matrices.

How would I create a design matrix (X) if I have ***x1 =1,2,3,4,....n*** , ***x2 =5,6,7,8....n*** and target ***T =9,8,7,6,....n*** and equation ***y= 1 + 21 + 32 + 412 + 5x2*x2*** . I randomly selected x1,x2 and T values . Now how do I create a design matrix (X) from the equation and observations given above ?

I know X is created from x1 and x2 following the equation y but I could not figure out how to do that .

Any help is appreciated . Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is using just regression coefficients for polynom 1. and 2. degree and interaction. The resulting design matrix has a shape:

[image]